# Google retiring "ranking" email action...how to replace Gmail/Schema.org actions

Tags: gmail, schema.org, google-schemas

I'm wondering how I can replace the functionality of the Google ranking action. 
I'm sending out email at the end of a ticket/support issue and want to be able to let customers state whether they are happy or not with the service they are getting without opening a web browser(inline button/link) or another method. I was trying to hijack the RSVP method however it appears as if the only answers you can set are "Yes, No, and, Maybe"

Looks like there is a lot in SCHEMA.ORG seems like Google has given up on any additions to the basic 3(Yes,No,Maybe) buttons with no real options.

Thanks

Comment: Based on their [release notes](https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/release-notes#review_action_deprecated), I'm afraid there is no workaround or alternative action type that we could use in exchange for review action.

Comment: Was also interested if they are developing this. 2013 with no new additions and a removal doesn't look good.